# Cant Draw Rectangle

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, rectangles

I am trying to just make a simple game, but for the game to work I need to be able to draw a rectangle. I added the paint method and told it to draw a rectangle and it didnt work. can someone please fix my code or tell me why a rectangle isn't being drawn?

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;



public class Graphic extends JPanel{

JFrame f = new JFrame("lol");
JPanel p = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

public Graphic(){

        f.setVisible(true);
        f.setSize(1600,900);
        //above decides if the frame is visible and the size of it
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //above makes the Jpanel which is in the frame
        JButton b1 = new JButton("Play");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("Stop");
        //above makes a button


        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

        c.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;

        p.add(b1,c);
        //c.gridx = 0;
        //c.gridy = 2;
        p.add(b2);

        f.add(p);
}
public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawRect(100,100,100,100);
}


public static void main(String args[]) {
    Graphic G = new Graphic();
}

}
```

Comment: What color should the rectangle be?

Answer (score 2):

You never actually *add* the panel to your `JFrame`. Replace:

```
f.add(p);
```

with

```
f.add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);
f.add(this);
```

Obviously, this will displace the `JPanel` `p` in the `BorderLayout.CENTER` position, so you need to decide where this be now located. You could add it up *NORTH* as shown.

---

Also you should override `paintComponent` rather than `paint`, while remembering to call `super.paintComponent(g)`.

See: [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Comment: @syb0rg Only if they created it (ie via `Graphics#create`), otherwise this will prevent anything from been painted to it

Comment: you said f.add(this) what do I write for "this"

Comment: Why should paintComponent be used over paint?

Comment: `paintComponent` offers far better paint performance using double buffering so should always be used in Swing

Comment: @Reimus I am quite new to this, where do I put Jpanel p and Borderlayout.center?

Comment: @Reimus I need it to be Borderlayout.CENTER and if it is the buttons wont appear

Comment: If you want the buttons & the rectangle to appear on the same panel, then you need to override `paintComponent` and add the buttons to the _same_ panel (rather than 2 panels)

Comment: @Reimeus How do you do that?

Comment: That will require a refactor. Instead of creating a separate panel `p`, add your buttons to the current `Graphic` class. If you have any issues then post a new question.